# Get multiple query values in one embedded script in Oracle in C#/VB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, oracle

I'm trying to get multiple query values for a DataSet in one embedded script in VB. SQL Server script working fine and the Oracle one is not.

```
<scripts id="getReportDetails">
    <mssql>
          SELECT GOAL_DESC, COALESCE(NULLIF(GOAL_EVALUATOR_COMMENT,''),'-') AS GOAL_EVALUATOR_COMMENT,COALESCE(NULLIF(GOAL_ASSESSEE_COMMENT,''),'-') AS GOAL_ASSESSEE_COMMENT
          FROM HS_HR_PEA_EXGOAL_TOIMPROVE
          WHERE TEMP_ID=@TEMP_ID AND TEMP_VERSION=@TEMP_VERSION AND FREQ_ID=@FREQ_ID AND EMP_NUMBER=@EMP_NUMBER

          SELECT EVALUATION_TYPE FROM HS_HR_PEA_TEMPLATE
          WHERE TEMP_ID=@TEMP_ID AND TEMP_VERSION=@TEMP_VERSION
    </mssql>
    <oracle>
          SELECT GOAL_DESC, COALESCE(NULLIF(GOAL_EVALUATOR_COMMENT,''),'-') AS GOAL_EVALUATOR_COMMENT,COALESCE(NULLIF(GOAL_ASSESSEE_COMMENT,''),'-') AS GOAL_ASSESSEE_COMMENT
          FROM HS_HR_PEA_EXGOAL_TOIMPROVE
          WHERE TEMP_ID=@TEMP_ID AND TEMP_VERSION=@TEMP_VERSION AND FREQ_ID=@FREQ_ID AND EMP_NUMBER=@EMP_NUMBER;

          SELECT EVALUATION_TYPE FROM HS_HR_PEA_TEMPLATE
          WHERE TEMP_ID=@TEMP_ID AND TEMP_VERSION=@TEMP_VERSION;
    </oracle>
</scripts>
```

Is there any way to get values from these two queries in one script in Oracle?

Comment: @Ajmot But I want to get these as two different tables not as one

Comment: your current query will return Two table, and one embedded script means??

Comment: @Ajmot means inside one `<oracle></oracle>` tag

Answer (score 1):

It depends very much on version of Oracle you use. On 11g the same approach as for SQL Server is not possible because it doesn't support implicit cursors. So the only way to achieve it to define two explicit cursors and consume them in .NET.

In Oracle 12 it's same simple as in SQL Server, however I experienced ODAC crashes when reading implicit cursors asynchronously.

I made an example for you:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=HQ_PDB_TCP;PASSWORD=oracle;USER ID=HUSQVIK"))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Oracle 11
        command.CommandText = "BEGIN OPEN :C1 FOR SELECT 1 FROM DUAL; OPEN :C2 FOR SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL; END;";
        var p1 = command.CreateParameter();
        p1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
        p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;       
        command.Parameters.Add(p1);

        var p2 = command.CreateParameter();
        p2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
        p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add(p2);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using (var reader1 = ((OracleRefCursor)p1.Value).GetDataReader())
        {
            reader1.Read();

            Console.WriteLine($"Reader 1 values: {reader1[0]}");
        }

        using (var reader2 = ((OracleRefCursor)p2.Value).GetDataReader())
        {
            reader2.Read();

            Console.WriteLine($"Reader 2 values: {reader2[0]}, {reader2[1]}");
        }

        command.Parameters.Clear();

        // Oracle 12
        command.CommandText = "DECLARE C1 SYS_REFCURSOR; C2 SYS_REFCURSOR; BEGIN OPEN C1 FOR SELECT 1 FROM DUAL; DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(C1); OPEN C2 FOR SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL; DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(C2); END;";
        using (var implicitReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            implicitReader.Read();

            Console.WriteLine($"Implicit cursor 1 values: {implicitReader[0]}");

            implicitReader.NextResult();
            implicitReader.Read();

            Console.WriteLine($"Implicit cursor 2 values: {implicitReader[0]}, {implicitReader[1]}");
        }
    }
}
```